# CakePHP app pointing to lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/View/Pages/home.ctp in production

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp

I'm in the process of trying to migrate my site from Cake 1.3.8 to Cake 2.4.4. Locally, in my dev environment, the process has been relatively painless, however, when I try to migrate my app files to a production server, it's failing.

I get a 200 response from my homepage, and I even get the static content from it(!), but the page that is displayed is the page located here: `lib/Cake/Console/Templates/skel/View/Pages/home.ctp`. It looks like that's the file that's being piped out of `$content_for_layout`.

All of my templates and pages survive the transit, so I don't know what the issue is, and the logs aren't telling me anything's wrong.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What migration strategy did you use? Incrementally migrating like this: 1.3->2.0->2.2->2.3->2.4? The migration docs seem to imply this is the way to go. http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices.html

Comment: Yes, I followed the docs exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that my `Pages` folder was incorrectly not capitalized. For some reason, my dev environment ignores this, but my prod environment enforces it.

Comment: It is looking like your production environment is on Linux, correct me if I'm wrong